# Float div elements one below the other

Tags: css, css-float

Can someone please check this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/sokajoyefahi/1/edit)

I'm trying to get rid of the white space left to Home Terms and Conditions-Affiliate Program-Our Company so that it will align on same row as sitelinks

Comment: One below the other is the default div behaviour.

Comment: `clear` the float: http://jsbin.com/sokajoyefahi/6/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
footer .row > div {
    clear: left;
}
```

It will make your sections "watch out" for any floating content above, and render below it.

If you want a nice way of doing stuff like this when working with float layouts in the future, [read this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). It's a common "hack" for web developers and it's good to know about it.

EDIT AFTER OP COMMENT:

You have set `float: left` on your headers (`<h4>`-tags). Remove that. And then make the sections that contain the headers float instead:

```
footer .row > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't explain well.

I've edited the JSBIN, can you please recheck that link? I want the other links below to SITE LINKS on same line.

Comment: Huh? Dou you want "Home-Terms and Conditions-Affiliate Program-Our Company-Account Login-Latest News-FAQ's-Contact-Support" in a single column?

Or do you want to get rid of the white space to the left of "Home-Terms and Conditions-Affiliate Program-Our Company"?

Comment: Yes sir, I want to get rid of the white space left to Home Terms and Conditions-Affiliate Program-Our Company so that it will align on same row as sitelinks. please help